# Google sheets plot frequency per day in a chart

Tags: google-sheets, charts, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to plot frequency per day from a column in a chart.

The column has entries for multiple dates of month and may have multiple entries per day. I want to plot those in a chart . Using X-axis as the date.

I have explored multiple options and it looks like I may have to use count-ifs but could not get in detail answer/explanation

[image: Sample Data].

Sample list:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18wF8Q3wEXSQDkRnSA4F1064rbKJmk-jw4A4xgcNAKVQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image: the graph]

[image: Sample formula tried by me]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18wF8Q3wEXSQDkRnSA4F1064rbKJmk-jw4A4xgcNAKVQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I comprehend that you want to plot that table into a graph that shows the multiple price frequency per day. If my assumption is right, you can use a scatter chart like this one:
[image: Scatter chart]

Comment: sorry, its not exactly what I intend to do. Price for a day, plus count for a day. there would be 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({QUERY({A2:B, ROW(C2:C)}, 
 "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1 limit 0"); 
 IF(QUERY(QUERY({A2:B, ROW(C2:C)}, 
 "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0)<>0, QUERY(QUERY({A2:B, ROW(C2:C)}, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"), 
 "select Col1 offset 1", 0), )},,99^99)), " "))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iSOzYAd5ehOOEij9Xa_YTfpmMKW01tvt0OLBryRY4xs/edit#gid=0)